# Problem while reusing model for new observations

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, r, linear-regression

I want to  build a model using R, save it and reloading it when required. I am able to save the model and reload it without any problem, however when i use the model along with predict statement, I am getting errors.

This is what i do:

> set.seed(345)
>   df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20))
>   df <- transform(df, y = 5 + (2.3 * x) + rnorm(20))
>
> ### model
>
> m1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
>
> ### save this model
>
> save(m1, file = "my_model1.rda")

### a month later, new observations are available:

> newdf <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20))
>
> ### load the model
>
> load("my_model1.rda")

When i use the above model to predict for new values, I am getting output values as "NA"

> predict(m1, newdata = newdf)

"NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA"  "NA" "NA"  "NA"  "NA"

I could able to see that the model has been loaded correctly by giving a print command

> print(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x
      4.792        2.119

Is there anything that I miss here?

Comment: That should work! are you sure there's no typo, say in `newdf`?

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani - Thanks for the reply, My code is similar one, as i could not copy that from my office network, i pasted this one. I did similar to this.

Comment: This is strange, b/c when you have the coefficients in this particular case then prediction is a simple algebra, but returning 'NA's should indicate a problem with new data not the loaded model!

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani - Thanks again. The model works if i use directly in the same programme. (means, build model and predict immediately for a new data). Where as I get into this problem only when i save the model, load again and then use it for prediction.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani - as you said, this has worked. The issue which was preventing from working is, one of the old models which was still in the R's Cache memory. I have removed that using rm=list(ls)) which has solved the problem. Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue :) cheers